# add fragment on another fragment in frame layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragment-shader, android-framelayout

I gonna add one `fragment` to another `fragment` in `frameLayout` but I do not want to replace. I gonna when click on `button` second `fragment` show up and when click on back key second `fragment` hide now . I do not want first `fragment` destroyed . what should I do?

**similar code:**

```
transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.frame_fragment_containers,new FragmentCate() , "fragcate");
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: When you are adding fragment in fragments' container, make sure you are adding in framelayout of fragment

Comment: that's right bro . i adding in frame layout of fragment . i gonna first fragment hide when second fragment added.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add fragment to another fragment, you can use getChildFragmentManager(). onActivityCreated of parent fragment, you can add another fragment just like below.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.My_Container_1_ID, "your fragment here")
                .commit();
    }
```